# I'm trying to deploy my node.js app to herokus but I get this Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/public'

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, multer, mkdir

here is the full error then Heroku gives me an H10 error code and goes into a crashed state:

[Full Heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4o0T.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Please show the code where you try to create that directory. Are you including a leading `/`?

Comment: Thank you for the heads up I found the issue with my problem. I was using multer but I had a typo in the file path when you do const upload = multer({ dest: 'images/' });  and so Heroku would crash and give the error you see